# How can i use option -std=c99 in vscode to run programs in c?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, c99, c89

I can only run program in C89, but how can i do it with c99? Sorry for a stupid question, I am a newbie

Comment: the compilation is done in `tasks,json`, add the `-std=c99` option in the compile statement, don't use code runner

Comment: You need to create and configure a `tasks.json` file to have a custom build. While [the VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/introvideos-cpp) barely mention C, you can still use it to configure build C applications.

Comment: VSCode is a frontend capable of using various compiler toolsets as backend. Some of these are *not* fully C99 compliant (at least they weren't last time I looked at them (cough) MSVC (cough). Please specify which compiler toolset you're using.

Comment: @DevSolar you need mote patience. Microsoft will support C99 by 2050

Comment: @0___________: Since they don't consider support for anything later than C89 "a priority" (their words), I'm not holding my breath. ;-)

Comment: @0___________ You really think they can move that fast?  :-D